# StreamReader "cannot be used like a method"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm getting the erro "CS1955 - Non-invocable member 'StreamReader' cannot be used like a method.

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Definir o objeto para leitura do arquivo
            System.IO.StreamReader leitor = System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            //Descarregar o conteúdo do arquivo na richTextBox1
            textoRichTextBox.Rtf = leitor.ReadToEnd();
            //Fechar o objeto de leitura do arquivo
            leitor.Close();
        }
```

Comment: You're looking for the `new` keyword.

Comment: thank you, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
using(var leitor = new System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName)) {
    textoRichTextBox.Rtf = leitor.ReadToEnd();
}
```

or just:

```
textoRichTextBox.Rtf = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```